# access instance of a class from a different class?

Tags: java

I have to create a user interface that allows the user to create a graph by adding vertices and edges. I have all the base coding done, and want to add a button to the gui to allow the addition of the vertex. i draw the graph from a canvas, in another class. Now my problem is, if i create the graph in the gui class, how do I access it from the canvas to draw it? Or if i create the graph in the canvas class, how do i let the button update the graph?
Not sure which code snippets to give...

Comment: You need to give more information than this. What are you using to create the UI?

Comment: Take a look at [Model-View-Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller).  Even if you don't follow the pattern it will get you thinking about keeping your model separate from your presentation.

Comment: Using swing and awt for the UI

Comment: The only real problem is that i dont know where to create the graph instance so that both the UI and the canvas can access it and read/update from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your canvas and button objects somehow need to coordinate. Either the button has to know the canvas, or the canvas has to know the button, or they both have to know the graph object which is provided to them by a third class (which could be the one which puts together the UI).

You could add a `getGraph()` method to one of the objects, to allow the necessary access.

Comment: Thanks! I have slightly changes my canvas, so that the graph is created outside a method, and added methods; that accept parametes from the UI class; which will add/remove things from the graph. Only just had the idea, hope it works!

Comment: It Wooorks! Thanks for the brilliant suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You should have some sort of data structure that stores the information about the nodes and edges.  Your canvas should read it to draw and your UI should insert/update/delete items from that structure.

Where ever you store this structure you will have to provide a reference to it or to methods to modify it.